# Including Json.NET in a Visual Studio extension

Tags: json.net, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I'm using JSON.NET in a Visual Studio extension and it's not included in the distribution ([by design by Microsoft](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/227430/required-assembly-reference-not-being-included-in.html)).

In the linked ticket they simply state that v9.0.1 should be used. And that supporting multiple VStudio versions "complicate things".

Another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50003033/vsix-newtonsoft-isnt-in-package-vs15-5-suppress-package) gives and answer which doesn't work in all cases.

I use a nuget package which in turn depends on Newtonsoft.Json 10.0.x. Is there any way that I can continue to use JSON.NET v10.x without causing any trouble for Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use AppDomain and wrap all Newtonsoft.json related call within new AppDomain:

```
myDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("myDomain", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence,
                                    new AppDomainSetup()
                                    {
                                        ApplicationBase = extensionPath,
                                        ConfigurationFile = Path.Combine(extensionPath, configurationFileName)
                                    });
```

The file configurationFileName should be shipped with your extension and its content looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```